# How to crop image in java?

Tags: java, swing, image-processing, crop

I'm using java to crop image when upload file, I set value and to try to crop but is not get correct size of image as I expected

This my code: (**updated**)

```
private BufferedImage cropImageSquare(byte[] image) throws IOException {        
    InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(image);
    BufferedImage originalImage = ImageIO.read(in);

    System.out.println("Original Image Dimension: "+originalImage.getWidth()+"x"+originalImage.getHeight());            

    BufferedImage croppedImage = originalImage.getSubimage(300, 150, 500, 500);
    System.out.println("Cropped Image Dimension: "+croppedImage.getWidth()+"x"+croppedImage.getHeight());


     return croppedImage;
}
```

my photo:

[image]

I want to crop image as above image (red line) but my code is seem incorrect.

How to crop image as expect?

Comment: Your code crops in a square form, yet the red line in your image clearly shows a non square form. Could you please clarify what you actually want? Also what is the correct size you expected? What are you experiencing instead?

Comment: @Ben, yes I see, image is just illustration for my code..

Comment: Then it's a really bad illustration that is not adding anything but confusion. Also still please add the remaining points I mentioned. "but is not correct size" is not really useful as we don't know what is correct for you.

Comment: your code uses the shorter side as the square size. You will crop only 2 side with that. That doesn't match your illustation.

Comment: Please clarify this part: "is not get correct size of image as I expected"

Comment: @jhamon: I'm sorry for not clear, I have updated my code yet !!

Comment: now, add the console output so we can undestand what you mean by incorrect size

Comment: @jhamon: meaning I want to crop image same as photo(red line), but my code: getSubimage(300, 150, 500, 500); is incorrect

Comment: @luongkhanh Based on you image and your original code, I get an image of `811x811` which is what I'd expect, based on what you code is doing

Comment: do you mean that your code has error, or the cropped image doesn't match your desired size ?

Comment: @hatched, yes exactly ^^

Comment: that was "either or" question, yes ist not an answer...

Comment: let's try something else. Add the resulting image. That will make it clear for everyone

Comment: @luongkhanh So, your input image is `1024x811` and your "target" image is `928x697`, which is roughly `0.906x0.859` scaling/difference - since the scaling is not the same for both dimensions, the question becomes, how were you thinking of determining it?  Is the red line just a "guide" of what you want to achieve or does it actually exist in your original image?

Comment: I guess he just mixed up coordinates with the width and height settings in `getsubimage`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to crop image as above image (red line) but my code is seem incorrect.

So, your input image is `1024x811` and your "target" image is `928x690`, which is roughly `0.906x0.8509` reduction/difference - so the real question is ... which one of those is the right value?

Through my testing, based on this image, `0.8509` produces the best result

[image: From][image: To]

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedImage crop = new Test().crop(0.8509);
        System.out.println(crop.getWidth() + "x" + crop.getHeight());
        ImageIO.write(crop, "jpg", new File("Square.jpg"));
    }

    public BufferedImage crop(double amount) throws IOException {
        BufferedImage originalImage = ImageIO.read(Test.class.getResource("Cat.jpg"));
        int height = originalImage.getHeight();
        int width = originalImage.getWidth();

        int targetWidth = (int)(width * amount);
        int targetHeight = (int)(height * amount);
        // Coordinates of the image's middle
        int xc = (width - targetWidth) / 2;
        int yc = (height - targetHeight) / 2;

        // Crop
        BufferedImage croppedImage = originalImage.getSubimage(
                        xc, 
                        yc,
                        targetWidth, // widht
                        targetHeight // height
        );
        return croppedImage;
    }

}
```

Now, this doesn't do any checks (`xc + targetWidth > imageWidth`), but I'm sure you can fill that out

Comment: Tks, you are so exactly, I can crop as expected.. How to increase height of image(no width) more a little, ex: 0.8509

Comment: Pass both a `width` and `height` value based on your needs

Comment: I don't got it, can you give me detail value of height ?

Comment: So, based on my calculations, the difference between the input and the output is `0.906x0.8509`, so, assuming you want to modify the width and height independently, then you need to pass a modifier for both

Comment: yes I got your explain ^^, just is my problem I don't know how to get value of height or width, where i can get this value ?

Comment: Well, that's the problem - what are you specific requirements?  Is the red rectangle a "guide" for our benefit or is it some "marker" generated into the file? Do you specifically have a "target size" the file must be cropped by?

Answer (score 1):

Code is working fine for me.

```
public class Test {

    public static void main( String[] args ) throws IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException {

        try{
              BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\Users\\guptab\\Pictures\\American.png"));
              ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
              ImageIO.write(image, "png", baos);
             byte[] res=baos.toByteArray();
             image = new Test().cropImageSquare(res);

        } 
        catch(Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Error");
        }
        }



    private BufferedImage cropImageSquare(byte[] image) throws IOException {        
        InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(image);
        BufferedImage originalImage = ImageIO.read(in);

        System.out.println("Original Image Dimension: "+originalImage.getWidth()+"x"+originalImage.getHeight());            

        BufferedImage croppedImage = originalImage.getSubimage(300, 150, 300, 600);
        System.out.println("Cropped Image Dimension: "+croppedImage.getWidth()+"x"+croppedImage.getHeight());


         return croppedImage;
    }
}
```

Output is:

```
Original Image Dimension: 1279x1023
Cropped Image Dimension: 300x600
```

Definition of getSubImage method:

```
BufferedImage java.awt.image.BufferedImage.getSubimage(int x, int y, int w, int h)


Returns a subimage defined by a specified rectangular region. The returned BufferedImage shares the same data array as the original image.
Parameters:x the X coordinate of the upper-left corner of the specified rectangular regiony the Y coordinate of the upper-left corner of the specified rectangular regionw the width of the specified rectangular regionh the height of the specified rectangular regionReturns:a BufferedImage that is the subimage of this BufferedImage.
```

So int x and int y (First two Parameters are coordinates of image, not dimensions), only int w, int h (last two parameters) are dimensions of the image which is working fine.