# Using BufferedImage in a thread-safe way efficiently?

Tags: java, swing, thread-safety, jpanel, bufferedimage

Let's say I have this simple `javax.swing.JPanel` component, which is only used to display a `BufferedImage`.

```java
public class Scratch extends JPanel {
    private BufferedImage image;

    public Scratch(BufferedImage image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
    }
}
```

Sometimes the `repaint()` method is called for this component, indicating that Swing should redraw it. However, the usage of the overridden `paintComponent` method is handled by Swing internally. Therefore, I cannot exactly control when the `BufferedImage` is read.

Now let's say I have some image-processing algorithms being performed on the injected `BufferedImage`. There are two ways these are commonly performed:

- Reading the image's current state and changing it with `setPixel`.
- Making a copy of the current image state (only interested in the RGB value matrix), carrying out the image processing by reading the original matrix and modifying the copied matrix, then replacing the original matrix by the copy. So that the new state would be rendered instead of the original into the UI.

Two questions:

- What would be the most efficient (fastest) thread-safe way for executing both of these processes? For maximum image processing performance.
- Would it be thread-safe to call `setPixel` on the original instance from a custom thread or would it need to be called in the Swing event queue to avoid conflicts with the `paintComponent` reading?

Maybe using `BufferedImage` is not the best way, in this case you may suggest other options as well. But I would currently like to focus on Swing with `BufferedImage`.

Comment: Are you referring to the `setPixel` method of the underlying `WritableRaster`? Apart from that it's not entirely clear what the ultimate goal is: Do you want to avoid that an "intermediate" state of the image is painted? And beyond that: Things become more complicated internally, regarding the "tracking" of images (see https://github.com/JetBrains/jdk8u_jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/sun/awt/image/SunWritableRaster.java - roughy: whether an image is held in VRAM or not).

Comment: Also, the current answer essentially proposes a "double buffering": Creating a *new* image that is modified, and simply "swapping" the old vs. new image at the end. Is this a viable option?

Comment: @Marco13 Iwas talking about `setPixel` of the `BufferedImage` object. However, there might be more efficient techniques which I haven't discovered. The ultimate goal is to reach maximum performance. Can I use my own threads to call `setPixel` or should I queue the processing algorithm to Swing. Showing the intermediate state is not a problem. But carrying out the processing on a copy and replacing the old image (or matrix) by the new one, is the *preferred* way because there are often complex algorithms which require the creation of a new image anyway (such as dilation and erosion).

Comment: The `BufferedImage` class does not have a `setPixel` method - do you mean `setRGB`? (A `setPixel` only exists in `WritableRaster`). When talking about maximum performance, then there are some details to consider. I assume that you're not talking about the performance of actually *painting* the final image (i.e. whether the `drawImage` call takes 20 or 50ms), and maybe not even about whether the `setPixels` call takes 50 or 100ms, but mainly about the raw processing on the pixels. Then it would be good to know the preferred pixel format - an `int[] rgb` array, I guess? Then I'd write some hints

Comment: A `BufferedImage` doesn't have much mutable state (other than its pixel data). You can't change its dimensions, color model/sample model or so. Any such change can only be achieved by creating a new `BufferedImage` instance. So the "worst" thing that will happen if the image is `repaint`ed while in the middle of an update, is you see some of the new pixel values mixed with some of the old. This can be easily fixed by forcing a repaint after you are done processing. You could probably also just ignore any repaints during processing, essentially "detaching" the image temporarily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, you never know when `repaint()` of the panel will be executed. To avoid any non-wanted views in the component, i would process the image in a background thread. This way, i would not care so much (of course i would) how much time the image processing will take. Finally, after processing the image, i would share it to the GUI (back to EDT thread).

Worth to mention, that the tool to run tasks in background in Swing, is a [Swing Worker.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) A swing worker will allow you to do long time tasks in background and then update the GUI in the proper thread (EDT - event dispatch thread).

I've created an example where frame is composed by an Image and a "process image" button.

When the button is pressed the worker starts. It process the image (in my case **it crops the image to 90%**) and finally "refresh" the view with the new image, nice and easy.

Also, in order to answer your question:

> Would it be thread-safe to call setPixel on the original instance from
>   a custom thread or would it need to be called in the Swing event queue
>   to avoid conflicts with the paintComponent reading?

You do not have to worry about what method you are going to use during the image process task. Just, do not update swing components there. Update them after the process.

**Preview:**

[image]

**Source code:**

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;

public class TestImage extends JFrame {
    private Scratch scratch;
    private JButton crop;

    public TestImage() {
        super("Process image");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        try {
            BufferedImage img = loadImage();
            scratch = new Scratch(img);
            getContentPane().add(scratch, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        crop = new JButton("Process image");
        crop.addActionListener(e -> processImage());
        getContentPane().add(crop, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        setSize(500, 500);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    private void processImage() {
        crop.setEnabled(false);
        crop.setText("Processing image...");
        new ImageProcessorWorker(scratch, () -> {
            crop.setEnabled(true);
            crop.setText("Process image");
        }).execute();
    }

    private BufferedImage loadImage() throws IOException {
        File desktop = new File(System.getProperty("user.home"), "Desktop");
        File image = new File(desktop, "img.png");
        return ImageIO.read(image);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> new TestImage().setVisible(true));
    }

    public static class Scratch extends JPanel implements ImageView {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = -5546688149216743458L;
        private BufferedImage image;

        public Scratch(BufferedImage image) {
            this.image = image;
        }

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
        }

        @Override
        public BufferedImage getImage() {
            return image;
        }

        @Override
        public void setImage(BufferedImage img) {
            this.image = img;
            repaint(); //repaint the view after image changes
        }
    }

    public static class ImageProcessorWorker extends SwingWorker<BufferedImage, Void> {
        private ImageView view;
        private Runnable restoreTask;

        public ImageProcessorWorker(ImageView v, Runnable restoreViewTask) {
            view = v;
            restoreTask = restoreViewTask;
        }

        @Override
        protected BufferedImage doInBackground() throws Exception {
            BufferedImage image = view.getImage();
            image = crop(image, 0.9d);
            Thread.sleep(5000); // Assume it takes 5 second to process
            return image;
        }

        /*
         * Taken from
         * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50562388/how-to-crop-image-in-java
         */
        public BufferedImage crop(BufferedImage image, double amount) throws IOException {
            BufferedImage originalImage = image;
            int height = originalImage.getHeight();
            int width = originalImage.getWidth();

            int targetWidth = (int) (width * amount);
            int targetHeight = (int) (height * amount);
            // Coordinates of the image's middle
            int xc = (width - targetWidth) / 2;
            int yc = (height - targetHeight) / 2;

            // Crop
            BufferedImage croppedImage = originalImage.getSubimage(xc, yc, targetWidth, // widht
                    targetHeight // height
            );
            return croppedImage;
        }

        @Override
        protected void done() {
            try {
                BufferedImage processedImage = get();
                view.setImage(processedImage);
                if (restoreTask != null)
                    restoreTask.run();
            } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            super.done();
        }

    }

    public static interface ImageView {
        BufferedImage getImage();

        void setImage(BufferedImage img);
    }
}
```